# System error 1219 has occurred

Tags: windows, networking, windows-command-prompt, net

I am trying to connect to a remote server and deploy a service there, through a deploy script.

I start by stating "Net use" and send the credentials for the server.

But here I get system 1219 error:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

I am not aware that I have any connections other than this one to the server.

I have tried net "use /delete" but was told that no connections were open to the server.

What gives?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seemed to help:
"net use * /del"

I still do not know what my initial mistake was.

Answer (score 38):

**1. Fire up a command prompt**

```
cmd.exe
```

**2. View current network shares**

```
C:\>net use
New connections will not be remembered.

Status       Local     Remote                    Network

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK           G:        \\srv\share               Microsoft Windows Network
OK           H:        \\fqdn\user$              Microsoft Windows Network
                       \\zombie-srv\share        Microsoft Windows Network
The command completed successfully.
```

**3. Remove zombie mounts**

```
C:\>net use /DELETE \\zombie-srv\share
\\zombie-srv\share was deleted successfully.
```

**4. Mount the share as another user**

```
C:\>net use z: \\zombie-srv\c$ /USER:domain\admin_user
Enter the password for 'domain\admin_user' to connect to 'zombie-srv':
The command completed successfully.
```

You can also try

```
net help use
```

for more details on how to operate the net command.

Comment: `net use * /del /yes` can be used in a script where you need to delete zombie shares with no intervention.

Comment: This was useful, just a small addition: I had started a Admin command window and before coming here already tried net use but it no connections. For some reason I thought to check from a non-admin command window and found a connection that I needed to delete.

Comment: this well-written answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: @MiserableVariable your comment is a valid answer on it's own. net use from admin command prompt vs a regular command prompt has tripped me up many times

Answer (score 6):

use IP address instead of server name? (see Multiple Credentials in a Single Windows NT Session http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q173199/ )

Answer (score 4):

I have found that if I mount a drive, disconnect, and then try to reconnect with different credentials, this error pops up.

`net use * /del` did not help.

`net use` shows no connections (checked with both a regular and an elevated prompt)

`ipconfig /renew` did not help either

I had to log out and log back in. I wonder where these credentials are cached :(

Comment: In case it helps anyone, I found that `net stop lanmanworkstation ; net start lanmanworkstation ; net start netlogon ; net start sessionenv` did the trick, without logging off.

Comment: I had a similar situation to this, and while trying JYD's net stop/start suggestions, something reminded me that the PC had been prepared for use on a domain and shipped to the end user, to be used over a c2s tunnel.  Somewhere along the line, something changed on the machine, and the user was logging on to the machine with a local ID having the same credentials as the (remote) Domain.  TLDR; - I changed the `/user:` parameter to `/user:DOMAIN\userid`, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem... a connection had been removed, and did not show up in a `net use` list was preventing a new connection.

Running `net use * /del` and then answering "N" seemed to clear it!

Comment: I had to answer "Y". But we had a lot of connections in our list... I think we bumped into some sort of limit, and the error message was not clear.

Comment: In Windows, the error messages are never clear. And how to find out what causes the error even less. Not talking about remedy...

Answer (score 1):

If you sometimes access the device with name (lookup) and other timers with IP address, this can happen.

Try accessing with another user by using IP instead of name.

```
net use \\192.168.0.108 /user:anotheruser
```

where 192.168.0.108 is the IP of zombie-srv

I know this answer comes very late, but this issue still happens to me every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Until Powershell takes over windows console completely, command prompt may be the simplest way to manage the issue.

1. Start a command prompt

`Start -> Run (or win-R) -> cmd.exe`

2. If you are attempting to mount a share on a server using a username that is different from the username for which you already have a connection to any share on the same server, you will first need to disconnect all connections to that server. You can view the connections using the below command.

`net use`

You will receive output similar to the following:

```
    New connections will not be remembered.
    
    Status       Local     Remote                    Network
    
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    OK           G:        \\srv\share               Microsoft Windows Network
    OK           H:        \\fqdn\user$              Microsoft Windows Network
                           \\zombie-srv\share        Microsoft Windows Network 
    The command completed successfully.
```

The "\zombie-srv\share" entry is not necssarily a zombie. These kinds of entries are created when you use a unc path for any reason. (typing `\\server\share` into explorer.exe for example)

3. Remove all the existing shares for the server you want to create the new connection to:

`net use \\server\share /delete`

Note that your share may actually be a deeper path, such as `\\server\homedrives\myusername`

4. At this point, you can attempt to reconnect.

`net use \\server\share /user:somedomain\someusername`

5. If you still get the dreaded 1219 error, you can perform the following commands to restart the smb client service, known as **lanmanworkstation**. It is often the case that this will be necessary in instances where the server hosting the share you want to connect to is the same share that your active directory indicated home drive is connected automatically for you at logon.

To view extraneous service dependencies (such as vmware-converter-server) you can run `sc enumdepend lanmanworkstation`

To stop lanmanworkstation, you'll need to first end the dependencies, commands for the standard dependencies follow.

`sc stop netlogon`

`sc stop sessionenv`

Then you can stop lanman workstation

`sc stop lanmanworkstation`

Then lastly, restart lanmanworkstation and then the dependencies

`sc start lanmanworkstation`

`sc start sessionenv`

`sc start netlogon`

At this point, you should be able to make a connection using another user:

`net use \\server\share /user:somedomain\someusername`

Answer (score 0):

I found this required a combination of **`net use * /del`** and disconnecting any previous shared folder sessions on the target server

Answer (score 0):

I found connections I forgot about in the Windows 10 Credential Manager under "Windows Credentials"