# batch script to copy files as within SMB\CIFS protocol

Tags: server-message-block, batch-processing

I'm trying to copy files from remote machine using construction like this

```
copy smb://DOMAIN;USERLOGIN:Password@100.10.10.10/folder/ C:/tmp/
```

it shows next message -

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I guess that win command "copy" works only with directories...
The main idea is to copy files over SMB protocol EXACTLY within userLogin and password.

So, I was serfing the internet and i found that "USE NET" may help me.
When i tried to use it, it said me that there are multiple connections on the same resource. 
Then i tried to  "USE NET \COMPNAME\folder DELETE" it shew that operation had been performed sucessful but message about multiple connections still the same during another attempts of using "USE NET".

Furthermore - if i could make such NET resource, would i be able to copy\delete files from that?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English.

---------Updated-----------------------

As Somesh mentioned i 've used USE NET for downloading files from multiple places
But unfortunately problem with multiple connetions within login and pass still exist. I couldnt find any active on current machine by using USE NET without an arguments.
Similar problem is here: [System error 1219 has occurred](https://serverfault.com/questions/57877/system-error-1219-has-occurred)

if it interesting to someone here is my sample-script:

```
@echo off
@echo initializing loop.
set disk="T"
set destination="D:\downloads\temp"
REM set user = "USER"
REM set password = "PASS"
REM set domain = "DOMAIN"

for /F %%S in (shares.txt) do (
    @echo start of performing: %%S

    @echo next step: mount network disk %disk%:
    pause
    DIR %disk%: 1>NUL && net use %disk%: /delete
    net use %disk%: %%S /persistent:no
        REM net use %%S /USER:%domain%\%user% %password% /persistent:no
    @echo next step: copy all files from %disk%: to %destination%

    pause
    xcopy %disk%:\* %destination% /s /i /c
    @echo next step: dismount network disk %disk%:
    pause
    net use %disk%: /delete
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

In a script, mount the SMB/CIFS share with the net command.

```
net use \\computername\sharename /persistent:no
```

You can use xcopy to copy the files to or from the SMB/CIFS share. After finishing copy, you could optionally remove the share from the Windows workstation.

```
net use \\computername\sharename /delete
```

You can get full options of the net command by running `net help use`.